# Rails Activerecord: Getting 404 rollback transaction error when patching belongs_to record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have the following simplified models, and an action in the controller in a rails project using Sqlite.

The update action in the cars controller was working fine until I added the garage model. Since garage has many cars and cars has one garage, I specified a foreign key relationship in the migration, with garage_id in the cars table.

After adding the "has_many :cars" and "belongs_to: garage" relationships in the models, the cars#update action stopped working with the "404 rolling back transaction" error. It seems there is some issue with the associations.

How do I specify the correct relationship between the models?

```
class Garage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  # car table has building_id as foreign key
  belongs_to :garage
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :option
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  # option table has car_id as foreign key
  belongs_to :car
end

class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @car.update(params[:color])
    @option.update(params[:seat])
    # getting "404 rolling back transaction" error.
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `belongs_to: garage, optional: true`.

Comment: Great! It worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: I really cannot understand the mindset of people who down-votes legitimate questions, without giving some valid reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Rails 5, `belongs_to` associations are assumed to be required by default. This will be validated every time you attempt to update an existing record.

If, as you suggest, `Garage` is a new model, your existing cars probably don't have a garage assigned yet. Making any other change to the car will check all validations, including the check for the existence of a garage. If your car still doesn't have one, the validation will fail, and the update transaction will rollback.

If you want to continue with cars validly belonging to **zero or one** garage, you can mark the association as optional:

```
belongs_to :garage, optional: true
```

If you intend to require all cars to be assigned to a garage at some point in the future, you can remove the `optional` clause once all cars have been updated. Or, you can bite the bullet and insist that all cars be assigned to garages before you can make any other changes to them. It's up to you, and the course of action you take will depend on your use case.

Incidentally, the validation failure should show up in `@car.errors` after you call `@car.update`. If you get rollbacks in future, that's always the best place to look first to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. That's really helpful!